# Importing Gmail Contacts using ASP.NET MVC 5 default UseGoogleAuthentication()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hello I am using default MVC Google Authentication for login using Google I get logged In but I want to Import Gmail Contact List As well

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "<<Client Id>>",
    ClientSecret = "<<Client Secret>>",
});
```

I have tried many ways like I Try like below but was not Successfull

```
var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "<<Client Id>>",
    ClientSecret = "<<Client Secret>>",

    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async context =>
        {
            //context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", context.User.GetValue("picture").ToString()));
            //context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("profile", context.User.GetValue("profile").ToString()));
            //context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("contacts", context.User.GetValue("contacts").ToString()));

            var userDetail = context.User;
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)));

            var gender = userDetail.Value<string>("gender");
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Gender, gender));

            var picture = userDetail.Value<string>("picture");
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", picture));

            //return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};

//googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
```

Is there any way to use Google Apis like Google.Contacts,Google.GData.Client and Google.GData.Extensions in Owin middleware using this app.UseGoogleAuthentication() function?